# Having a function only output the numberic answer

Tags: r, function, sapply

I was wondering if there is a way I can have `Gi1` an subsequently `UrUr` in the R code below **only provide the NUMBERIC ANSWER and NOT the extra word** `B10` that currently comes with the numberic answer?

**Note:** I'm aware of using `[[ith output]]` but I will need that function itself to provide purely number from the begining so I don't need to use many `[[]]` later in my code.

```
 library(BayesFactor)

 ttype = 1
 t = -.742
 N1 = 102
 N2 = ifelse(ttype==1, NA, 102)

 rscale = sqrt(2)/2
 tl = 1     
 dexp = -1 


 Gi1 <- function(x) {
 ttest.tstat(t, N1, ifelse(ttype==1, F, N2),
 nullInterval = c(ifelse(dexp==-1, -Inf, Inf), 
 ifelse(tl==1, 0, Inf)),rscale = x, simple = TRUE) }

UrUr <- sapply(c(1/2, 1, sqrt(2)/2 ), Gi1)
UrUr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `unname` within the `Gi1`:

```
Gi1 <- function(x) {
 unname(ttest.tstat(t, N1, ifelse(ttype==1, F, N2),
             nullInterval = c(ifelse(dexp==-1, -Inf, Inf), 
                              ifelse(tl==1, 0, Inf)),rscale = x, simple = TRUE)) }
```

And then it will be fine.

```
> UrUr <- sapply(c(1/2, 1, sqrt(2)/2 ), Gi1)
> UrUr
[1] 0.3015327 0.1579931 0.2197861
```